# Instantiate UITabBarViewController with selectedIndex

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to instantiate a UITabBarViewController with preselected Index. However, the code below instantiates the TabBar with incorrect selectedIndex. What am I doing wrong.? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Visits", bundle: nil)
        let visitsController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VisitsTabBarViewController") as! VisitsTabBarViewController

        visitsController.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further please? I mean what is the expected selected index and what is the actual selected index?

Comment: expected selected Index = 1 and actual is some really large value (seen by putting a breakpoint in viewDidLoad). I am wondering if the problem happens because the selectedIndex gets set only after viewDidLoad.

Comment: I'm gonna need to see a bit more of the code to look at your implementation and suggest a solution. I'm assuming you are using this code in AppDelegate.

Comment: Btw, that huge number is `NSNotFound` which means that no selection has been made.

Comment: Thanks Malik. Yes, that number was a big clue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. The solution is to set a property inside the TabBarViewControllere and not use the selectedIndex when I am instantiating the TabBarViewContoller like shown

```
class VisitsTabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
var index = 0
....

func viewDidLoad() {
      selectedIndex = index
}

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Visits", bundle: nil)
    let visitsController 
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VisitsTabBarViewController") as! VisitsTabBarViewController

visitsController.index = 1
```

Then when I instantiate the TabBarViewController, I set this index property as shown above. That seemed to fix it.